Angular returning but not returning array of objects from rest API call
FIXED:
--
The problem has been fixed. JSON was returning from the backend "certification". Because of this, I was unable to access it due to my front end model using "certifications". I changed the entity on the backend to "certifications" and it started working. Thanks everyone!
--
I am making an rest api to a java backend with angular. When making the call it returns an array of Users. These users also have an array of certifications as well. When I console.log() one of the users to test it, it shows the array of certifications in json within the inspect of chrome. When I try to log just 1 of the certifications it doesn't show. It also does not show on the page either. Could this possibly be because of some kind of lazy loading?
This code snippet shows an empty array of certifications in chrome
loadUsers() {
    this.userServ.getUsers().subscribe(
      (users) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.viewUsers = this.users.map((x) => x);
        console.log(this.viewUsers[0].certifications);
      },
      (noUsers) => {
        console.log('Error gettings users from service');
        console.log(noUsers);
      }
    );
  }

While this code snippet will show both certifications attached to viewUsers[0] once expanded in the chrome inspect.
loadUsers() {
    this.userServ.getUsers().subscribe(
      (users) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.viewUsers = this.users.map((x) => x);
        console.log(this.viewUsers[0]);
      },
      (noUsers) => {
        console.log('Error gettings users from service');
        console.log(noUsers);
      }
    );
  }


Rest API call returning only one object. You have used wrong API call.

Do you mutate your data by any chance? Try to wrap the console.log in a JSON.stringify as if you mutate an object it may display the new value in the console..

I'm only printing off the 0 index of that api call, it pulls more than one object from the backend.
I haven't mutated it I don't think? I don't know much about mutating, but i'll try a stringify

another approach is to use async pipe instead of subscribe in your component ;)
